# real numbers in base 2 - how the infinite series (Σ(b/2^n)) converge to a number in [0,1]?

Tags: number-theory

Any real number in $[0,1]$ has a unique binary decimal representation 0.bbbbb, where each b is either $0$ or $1$. Numerically, $0.b_1 b_2 b_3 b_4 b_5...=\sum^{\infty}_{i=1}(b_n/2^n) $
(***b_1=b-sub-one) 
where the infinite series converge to a number in $[0,1]$.
The question is- how does it possible for this series "to converge to a number in $[0,1]$" for example, how $1/3$ can be expressed using this series? Is there a proof for that statement?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You've asked two converse questions: (1) does this series always converge to a real number (2) can every real number (e.g. pi) be written as a series this way. It's unclear what you actually want answered.

Comment: the are numbers that don't have a unique representation in the diadic system: $1/2=(1,0,0,0, ...)=(0,1,1,1,1...)$. You receive tne bounds from estimating with the geometric series. $0\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n/2^n \leq 1$

Answer (score 2):

Such expansions will *not* generally be unique. For example, $.0\overline1$ and $.1$ both represent $\frac12$ in binary. We can prove the existence of such expansions, though.

For any positive real $x$, I will denote $f(x)$ to be the least positive integer $n$ such that $2^{-n}<x$.

Suppose $x\in[0,1]$ with $x\neq 0$. We define the sequence of $b_n(x)$'s recursively by $$b_1(x)=\begin{cases}0 & \text{if }f(x)>1\\1 & \text{otherwise,}\end{cases}$$ and $$b_{n+1}(x)=\begin{cases}0 & \text{if }f\left(x-\sum_{k=1}^n b_k(x)2^{-k}\right)>n+1\\1 & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

You should show that for all $n\geq 1$, we have $$\sum_{k=1}^nb_k(x)2^{-k}<x,$$ and that $$x=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^nb_k(x)2^{-k}.$$ You can then show that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n(x)2^{-n}$$ is the unique *non-terminating* binary expansion of $x$, for any $x\in(0,1]$.

---

As a side note, for any rational $x$, this expansion should be repeating eventually. Try to use it to compute, for example, the expansion of $\frac13$, yourself.

Comment: Oops: I didn’t see those last two lines before I posted my (now-deleted) supplementary answer.